# Generating a PDF with an image continuously falls with a request timeout

Tags: tcpdf, prestashop-1.6

Generating a PDF using TCPDF in PrestaShop 1.6 with an image ends with a request timeout while requesting the same image inside the server.

The PDF is generating fine for the ones without the image.

We are generating E-ticket as PDF for the customers who purchased our ticket and we send them as email attachment. Also, we have given them the possibility to generate the E-ticket PDF when they click on the button on their order history. But that too is not getting generated.

Comment: there might be permission issue with the image that you are trying to use....

Comment: I already set the permissions to 777 for the image. Still facing the issue.

Comment: have you checked if the library you are using supports <img> tag, if yes please share some code you are using so that I can identify the problem

Comment: When I provide an image URL that is located outside my server the PDF is generating fine. But whenever I place the image inside my server and calls that image for pdf generation it falls with an error like 504 request timeout.

Comment: have you tried to open the image by visiting the image directly

Comment: Yes I am able to open the image directly through browser